# set-cookie header not served from chrome disk cache?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, http-headers, httpresponse

I have a server that is supposed to set a cookie `abc` like so `Set-Cookie: abc=29cf700f;Max-Age=15552000;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure`
But, I don't see it in the response headers. After checking,I see that I do get the header in the response but not when the response is [served from disk cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lZEn.png). Does serving response from disk cache (I am mainly trying with Chrome but I see the same behaviour with Edge browser as well) always strip these headers? Why is this the case?

Comment: Hey. Did you find any solution for the issue?

Comment: no unfortunately. are you facing the same issue?